# ¿Cómo puedo generar un identificador en base a otros campos dentro de mis tablas en MySQL?

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, trigger, insert

Mi propósito es generar una columna en una tabla **Usuarios** que se llene automáticamente en base a los datos ingresados en las columnas *nombre* y *apellido*. Actualmente estoy utilizando un trigger con concatenación para realizar esta actividad, sin embargo, al momento de ingresar los campos el valor concatenado de ID me lo devuelve como "0", ¿podrían decirme a qué se debe esto? Y si es posible, cómo solucionarlo.

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
CREATE TABLE Usuarios (ID int not null key auto_increment, nombre varchar(20) not null, 
apellido varchar(20) not null, code varchar(12) not null);
```

Y mi trigger es el siguiente:

```
CREATE TRIGGER conca
BEFORE INSERT ON usuario FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN SET NEW.code = CONCAT(NEW.ID,substring(NEW.nombre,1,2),substring(NEW.apellido,1,2));
END
```

Para ingresar datos:

```
INSERT INTO Usuarios (nombre, apellido) VALUES ('Miguel','Valdez');
```

Con esto, al momento de mostrar los datos dentro de la tabla de usuarios, obtengo el siguiente resultado:

```
+----+--------+----------+-------+
| ID | name   | apellido | code  |
+----+--------+----------+-------+
|  1 | Miguel | Valdez   | 0MiVa |
+----+--------+----------+-------+
```

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es verdad, no sé por qué pone un 0, sospechaba que era cuestión de casting pero tampoco, así que lo solucioné sin usar el **new**, sino calculando el **último id** e **incrementando unidad**, quedaría así:

- **Opción 1: editando el trigger desde phpMyAdmin o MySQL Workbench**

```
BEGIN
declare id_var int default (select max(id) from usuarios);
set id_var =id_var+1;
SET NEW.code = CONCAT(id_var,substring(NEW.nombre,1,2),substring(NEW.apellido,1,2));
END
```

- **Opción 2: borrando el trigger existente y ejecutando desde consola**

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER conca
BEFORE INSERT ON usuarios FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
declare id_var int default (select max(id) from usuarios);
set id_var =id_var+1;
SET NEW.code = CONCAT(id_var,substring(NEW.nombre,1,2),substring(NEW.apellido,1,2));
END;
$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Si estás en MySQL arriba de 5.7, mejor usa una columna calculada:

```
ALTER TABLE usuario
ADD COLUMN gen_code AS
CONCAT(ID,substring(nombre,1,2),substring(apellido,1,2));
```

También revisa la documentación https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html ya que podrías usar Stored o Virtual como opciones, tiene mejor performance stored ya que sólo se calcula el valor al hacer insert o update, pero consume un poco de espacio, Virtual no consume espacio pero se calcula al vuelo entonces consume más recursos si son muchas filas devueltas en una consulta que incluya esa columna.

Comment: Intenté utilizar generated always pero no me lo permitió debido al auto_increment del campo ID "Function or expression 'AUTO_INCREMENT' cannot be used in the GENERATED ALWAYS AS clause of `ID`"

Comment: Prueba sin generated always

Answer (score 1):

Prueba lo siguiente sino:

CREATE TRIGGER conca
BEFORE INSERT ON usuario FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN SET NEW.code = CONCAT(OLD.ID,substring(OLD.nombre,1,2),substring(OLD.apellido,1,2));
END